# Redirecting subdomain to another subdomain in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, zones, hosted

How can I redirect my alpha.example.com subdomain to -> dev.example.com subdomain in AWS route 53?

I think to do it that way but I am not sure if this will work, so if you can help me :)

1. Entering in the hosted zone example.com
2. Choosing the CNAME of the alpha.example.com, Edit Record
3. Activating "Alias" option
4. "Route traffic to", Choose endpoint: "Alias to another record in this hosted zone", Choose record "dev.example.com", Routing policy "simple routing".
5. Save

Is this enough to do the redirect? My point is when they open the alpha.example.com to redirect them to the subdomain dev.example.com

Comment: When a user loads Alpha, if you want it to display the Dev website but keep the alpha URL/subdomain, then the CNAME would work. Just keep in mind that the Dev servers need to be configured to respond to requests using the Alpha subdomain. If you want the Alpha subdomain to move users to the Dev subdomain (URL change), then you need something to tell the browser to "go to Dev instead", which is usually a 301 or 302 redirect response. To serve the response you need a server, which can be EC2, an S3 website, CF with Lambda, or a few other options. Do whichever is best for your knowledge/budget.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think redirects can be done in Route53. Alias records are not for redirection. You will need to use something at layer 7 - i.e. an http(s) redirect or similar.

I typed your question into Google and got [advice from AWS Repost](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/route-53-redirect-to-another-domain). In short, the best option may be to create an S3 bucket and set it up to do a redirect, as documented [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53).

S3 bucket with web hosting and a redirect is an easy way to do this, without having to run a web server.

Comment: Okay, at layer 7 the application layer, you mean to do some configuration on the web server ? Like proxy or redirection from there ?

Comment: Yep. I'll edit.

Comment: Cheapest/easiest option is probably S3 setup for web hosting with a redirect plus CloudFront and ACM (to support TLS/https). I reuse a few resources we need for other parts of our site and have an ALB with a Lambda target (complex redirect rules), but an ALB rule alone could do it. Provisioning an ALB just for this use case is probably too expensive. Lambda@Edge or CloudFront functions should be able to handle this also. If your Dev system is running a webserver (nginx/apache/IIS/etc), you can configure the redirect there as well.